How to eliminate the periodic functions in Eq.3?
The figures are shown in the link
The equation in fig.1 can be transformed to the one in fig.2. Using ‘atan’, we can turn the periodic function ‘tan’,which is on the left of Eq.1, to the sum of ‘atan’ and l*π. However, for the case of fig.3, such method cannot be applied.
$$
\tan\left( \frac{q k_0 d}{\rho} \right) =
\frac{
\rho \frac{\epsilon_1 + \epsilon_3}{\epsilon_z}
}
{
1-\rho^2 \frac{\epsilon_1 \epsilon_3}{\epsilon_z^2}
}
$$
$$
q = \frac{\rho}{k_0 d} \left[
\arctan \frac{\epsilon_1 \rho}{\epsilon_z} + 
\arctan \frac{\epsilon_3 \rho}{\epsilon_z} + \pi l
\right]
$$
$$
M = a \cot b +  b \cot a
$$
Anyway to combine the two ‘cot’s on the right? If not, any methods to eliminate the periodic functions in Eq.3, and gain a function only contain aperiodic functions and the term l*π. The first two equations derive from the PDF (Eq 70/71).Much obliged!

Use the  arctan  sum formula
$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{a+b}{1- a b}\right)=\tan^{-1}( a)+\tan^{-1}( b)$$

I tried, it doesn’t work
